# How to conditionally set properties on XY bar chart in amCharts v4?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amcharts4

Hi I would like to format my XY Bar chart so that if a data value is 0, instead of showing the bulletLabel for that value in the center of the bar it will show it located at the front of the chart outside.

I would like to apply these properties to the bullet label:

```
labelBullet.label.horizontalCenter = 'left';
labelBullet.locationX = 0;
labelBullet.label.truncate = false;
labelBullet.label.hideOversized = false;
```

I would thought about using an adapter, but I am not sure how to write it. Here is my sad attempt:

```
labelBullet.label.adapter.add('label', function (value, target) {
    if (!target.dataItem) {
    return value;
    }
    var values = target.dataItem.values;
    if (values.valueY.value === 0) {
       labelBullet.label.horizontalCenter = 'left';
       labelBullet.locationX = 0;
       labelBullet.label.truncate = false;
       labelBullet.label.hideOversized = false;
    }
});
```

I am not sure how to check the data value or tell it that I want to apply those properties if the data point value is 0.

Here is my series creator:

```
let series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.name = id[0].toUpperCase() + `${id}`.slice(1);
series.dataFields.valueX = field;
series.dataFields.categoryY = 'school';
series.sequencedInterpolation = true;
series.columns.template.height = am4core.percent(30);
series.columns.template.tooltipText = '{categoryY}\n {name}: [bold]{valueX}[/]';

let labelBullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
labelBullet.locationX = 0.5;
labelBullet.label.text = '{valueX}';
labelBullet.label.fill = am4core.color('#fff');
labelBullet.label.hideOversized = true;
```

Here is a sample of data:

```
[
    {
     school: "Fort Lewis College",
     totalInBaseField: "33"
    },
    {
     school: "Adams State University",
     totalInBaseField: "0"
    }
    {
     school: "University of Colorado Colorado Springs",
     totalInBaseField: "141"
    }
]
```

The result should like like this:
Here is bar with value > 0

[value > 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klz5b.png)

Here is bar with value === 0

[value === 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Sn9B.png)

This is the desired change:

[if value === 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmDu9.png)

I was trying to follow this post as an example:
[How to conditionally set colors and make gradient to pie chart slices in amCharts v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56441021/how-to-conditionally-set-colors-and-make-gradient-to-pie-chart-slices-in-amchart)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Adapters for Bullet](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/bullet/#Adapters)
- [Adapters for LabelBullet](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/labelbullet/#Adapters) (which extends `Bullet`)
- [Adapters for Label](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/label/#Adapters)

To set these properties:

```
labelBullet.label.horizontalCenter = 'left';
labelBullet.locationX = 0;
labelBullet.label.truncate = false;
labelBullet.label.hideOversized = false;
```

you should try an adapter for each property.

Note that an adapter must *return* a value. So you should try something like that:

```
labelBullet.label.adapter.add('horizontalCenter', function(x, target) {
    if(!target.dataItem) {
      return x;
    }
    var values = target.dataItem.values;
    if(values.valueY.value === 0) {
       return 'left';
    } else {
      return 'right';
    }
});

labelBullet.adapter.add('locationX', function(x, target) {
    if(!target.dataItem) {
      return x;
    }
    var values = target.dataItem.values;
    if(values.valueY.value === 0) {
       return 0;
    } else {
      return SomethingElse;
    }
});

labelBullet.label.adapter.add('truncate', function(x, target) {
    if(!target.dataItem) {
      return x;
    }
    var values = target.dataItem.values;
    if(values.valueY.value === 0) {
       return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
});
```

etc.